# What is purpose of the "rtmGetU" define in the Simulink Embeded Coder generated C code

Tags: c, matlab, embedded, real-time, simulink

I have Simulink Embedded Coder output model code. One of header file includes;

```
#ifndef rtmGetU
#define rtmGetU(rtm) ((rtm)->ModelData.inputs)
#endif
```

After saw the code block in the header, I tried to generate my own Simulink model embedded code but the output not include the `rtmGetU` define.

I wonder what is the purpose of the `rtmGetU` define and how can I generate the `rtmGetU` code for my own model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rtmGetU` is a macro for conveniently getting the data that is being fed into any `Inport`s in the model that the code is generated from.

It will only be in the generated code if your model has any Inports (at the highest level of the model.)